# Is there a way to know the value of a variable in an if statement without knowing what the variable is?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to find out the value of the second variable in the if statement without knowing what the variable is.

EX:

```
//a, b, and c are controlled by the user in input boxes.
let a = "Josh"
let b = "James"
let c = ""
if (a.length!== 0 && b.length !== 0|| a.length !== 0 && c.length !== 0){
```

Here I want to check if a equals the value that the length doesn't equal 0. In this case b.

Ex:

```
if (a == secondVariable){
alert("WOOH")
}
```

I know I can write

```
if (a.length !== 0 && b.length !== 0){
if (a == b){
alert("WOOH")
}
} else if (a.length !== 0 && c.length !== 0){
if (a == c){
alert("BOOH")
}
} else {
alert("")
}
```

But this is a lot of code and I have a lot more variables to check in my code. Is there a more efficient way to write this? **Thank you**

Comment: Look into the javascript concepts of truthy and falsey.   `b || c` will give you the value of b if it has a value, or c if b doesn't have a value.   You should expand on what happens when `a` has a value, vs when it does not, and the same for `b` and `c`.  You have 8 cases to consider when you examine `a` does/does not have value, `b` does/does not have value and `c` does/does not have value.

Comment: I would just compare the values. If `a != c`, `a != c` whether `a.length != 0 && c.length != 0` or not.

Comment: Get value of something you don't know? Can you get a phone number for a someone without knowing their name? This is what seems to be "a bit unclear". Additionally, are all three inputs required to have something input? Why no use the `required` attribute on the input element and completely skip the `.length` steps? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the ifs.  Also you only need to check the length of one thing if you are also comparing it vs other thing.  Also there is a shortcut coercing the length property to a boolean:

```
if (a.length && a == b) {
  alert("WOOH");
}
if (a.length && a == c) {
  alert("BOOH");
}
```

Comment: What is the shortcut

Comment: check (a.length) instead of (a.length !== 0) like I did above